# ClassNotFoundError even though class is included in lib/ext folder in Jetty 9.2.2

Tags: jetty, installation, jetty-9

Just want to ask about my problem. I am trying to setup a jetty server and included my own webapp. I put the web application in the webapp folder of jetty server. I also included the necessary libraries needed by the web application in lib/ext folder of jetty, it is not included in the war file. when i run the jetty server and access the webapp, i get the 'NoClassDefFoundError'.

I run the jetty server using the 'java -jar start.jar'. I am also sure that the jar file which contains the class that causes the error is in the classpath.

Did i miss something?
Thank you.

Comment: i've managed to make it work. i just added an xml file that is the same filename of the war file. the xml file contains the parameter "setExtraClassPath" and pointed the library that causes the classnotfounderror.